# Windows 7 shuts down automatically every few minutes

Tags: windows-7

I have an Intel Core i3 system with 250 GB HDD and 2 GB RAM, running Windows 7. My system is two years old.

It frequently shuts down. Although the CPU light is on, the monitor displays "no signal".  I'm not even able to work on it continuously for ten minutes.

I thought it might be because of the OS and I formatted my C disk too, but that didn't help. What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like a possible heat issue...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a `RAM` or `VGA` problem.
Maybe just cleaning up memory will solve it. 
Pulling off your memory and cleaning it with isopropyl alcohol is an option.

I always say that at first, the best choice is to make a complete clean in the whole system: MB, RAM, VGA, CPU, all the contacts from the HD cables and power supply.

If that not solve it, at least you'll be aware that it could be a physic problem, like  overheat.

[**HERE**](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/cleaning-the-inside-of-your-pc/) is a good tutorial on how to do it.

**JUST BE CAREFUL** and pay attention. The inside case has real fragile components that needs extreme attention to clean.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the automatic reboot on system failure in Windows. That might leave the system showing an error message before it goes down.
Also check the Windows Event Log for error messages. Sometimes there is something useful there.

Some possible causes:

Could be overheating: Is the inside of the case dust-free and are all the fans working ?

Re-seating the RAM and the Video-card in their sockets might help if it is a bad contact thing. (This may develop over time as the system heats up and cools down when being used/unused.)

Bad RAM: Go to http://www.memtest.org/ and download the ISO or USB version of the test tool.
Downloading and burning the ISO is best done from a stable computer...
Just run the basic test. If this gives RED errors first re-seat the RAM strips and re-test. If that doesn't help replace the RAM. (If you have multiple strips of RAM it may be just one of them is flaky. So test them one at a time to find out which one.)